# $(n-2)$-degree curve passing through $n(n-1)/2$ midpoints

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

It is known that in the plane, there is an unique conic passing through given $5$ points. 
For any $4$  points, there is 6 segments which vertex from these points.
It is known that $6$ midpoints of these segments lie on a conic
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_conic .

Now it is known that there is an unique $(n-2)$-degree curve passing through $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-1$ points.
Given $n$ points. We determine $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ midpoints of segments whose vertex are $2$ of these $n$ points.
My question is whever there is a $(n-2)$-degree curve passing through these $n(n-1)/2$ midpoints?

Comment: The set of six midpoints of a quadrangle is centrally symmetric with respect to the barycentre of 4 vertices. This itself yields that it is inscribed to a conic. Did you check your conjecture for $n=5$ on some random configuration?

Comment: I am not able to test it yet as I do not know how to draw a curve with degreee more than 2 yet.

Comment: there should be such function in computer software, but in any case you may check whether the $10\times 10$ determinant of the matrix $f_i(x)$, where $f_i$ runs over monomials of degree at most 3, and $x$ runs over the midpoints of your 5 points, does vanish.

Comment: In any case, it is false for n=3. Perhaps n=4 is the only case.